# OAuth inside Spotify app

Tags: javascript, oauth, spotify

I am trying to get `OAuth` authentication done inside a Spotify app. By default, `window.open` is blocked, and I am not sure if there is any way to work around that. So, I was wondering what is the best way to handle that. I want to be able to do the following: 
1) Redirect the user to the auth link 
2) Once they're authenticated, I want to be able to get notified to handle the return URL and extract the access token from it.

A few options, I am considering: `1) IFrame` `2) $.ajax() -- problem is, this doesn't seem to load all javascript/css files from the auth url properly.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `auth.showAuthenticationDialog()` API is just what you're after. It'll pop up a dialog for you showing the given URL, then give you back the parameters when the return URL is called. Documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/09321954e7.html).

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var auth = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/auth');

auth.showAuthenticationDialog('http://www.last.fm/api/auth/?api_key=LAST_FM_API_KEY&cb=sp://my_app_name', 'sp://my_app_name', {

    onSuccess : function(response) {
        // Response will be something like 'sp://my_app_name?token=xxxxxxx'
        console.log("Success! Here's the response URL: " + response);
    },

    onFailure : function(error) {
        console.log("Authentication failed with error: " + error);
    },

    onComplete : function() { }
});
```